# getCount() not working in SQLite in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

As part of my application I have to insert questions and answers into a database in android and retrieve them and add dynamically to the layout.
I am able to insert into the database but unable to retrieve from it.
Also, getCount() method is returning 133 when there are only 5 tuples in the table.
My code is-

```
public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Answers";
private static final String TABLE_OOPBASICS = "oopBasics";
private static final String KEY_QUESID = "ques_id";
private static final String QUESTION = "question";
private static final String ANSWER = "answer";

public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_OOPBASICS_TABLE = 
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_OOPBASICS+ "("
            + KEY_QUESID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," 
            + QUESTION + " VARCHAR(300),"
            + ANSWER + " VARCHAR(100)" +")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_OOPBASICS_TABLE);
     Log.d(tag,"rows inserted");
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_OOPBASICS);
    onCreate(db);
}


// Adding new QUESTION
void addQuestion(Questions ques) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(QUESTION, ques.getQuestion()); 
    values.put(ANSWER, ques.getAnswer()); 
    db.insert(TABLE_OOPBASICS, null, values);
    db.close(); 
}
// Getting questions Count
public int getTotalRows() {
    int count=0;
    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_OOPBASICS; 
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null); 
    if (cursor != null) 
    {
        count = cursor.getCount(); 
        cursor.close();
         Log.d(tag,"in cursor closed");
    } 
    return count; 
    }

    public String getQuesWithId(int i) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = null; 
    String ques = ""; 
    String cols[]={KEY_QUESID,QUESTION};
    try{
        cursor = db.query(TABLE_OOPBASICS,cols,KEY_QUESID+"=i",null,null,null,null);
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0)
        { 
            cursor.moveToFirst(); 
            ques = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("question"));
            } 
         Log.d(tag,"at get questn closing");
        return ques; 
        }

    finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
    }  

public String getAnswer(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String cols[]={ANSWER};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_OOPBASICS,cols,KEY_QUESID+"=i",null,null,null,null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    String ans= cursor.getString(6); 
    return ans;

}

}
```

And to add dynamically to the layout

```
public class JavaHome extends Activity {
DataBaseHandler db;
SQLiteDatabase sdb;
int n;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_java_home);
    db=new DataBaseHandler(this);
    sdb=db.getWritableDatabase();
    db.addQuestion(new Questions("To which type of paradigm does Java belong    to?","OOP"));
    Log.d(tag,"1 row inserted");

db.addQuestion(new Questions("Which command is used to compile Java code?","javac"));
db.addQuestion(new Questions("What should be the name of Java class file ?","Class name"));
 db.addQuestion(new Questions("Which control structure exists in Java which does not exist in C and C++?","for-each"));
 db.addQuestion(new Questions("What is runtime polymorphism called?","Overriding")); 

     int i=db.getTotalRows();
    for( n=0;n<i;n++){
        LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(this);
        String ques=db.getQuesWithId(n);
        String ans=db.getAnswer(n);
        TextView tvq=new TextView(this);
        tvq.setText(ques);
        TextView tva=new TextView(this);
        tva.setText(ans);
        ll.addView(tvq);
        ll.addView(tva);
        setContentView(ll);

    }
}

public class Questions {
int _quesno;
String question;
String answer;

public Questions(String question,String answer){
    this.question=question;
    this.answer=answer;
}

public String getQuestion()
{
    return this.question;
}
public String getAnswer()
{
    return this.answer;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> getCount() method is returning 133 when there are only 5 tuples

Does this number increse every time you run your app ?
I think that every time you run your app your code inserts more entries to the db. If that is the case reinstall your app and add constant id's to your entries.

Thinking long term you should get fomiliar with `ContenProvider` as an efficent way to handle your db.

Please see:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: I tried by changing the name of the database, but still its giving wrong count

Comment: Is `getCount()` constant every time you run your app?

Comment: No, sometimes its returning 0, even after records are inserted.